# C# Google Calendar : How do i get the calendarId of a user that just logged in?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api

I need to know how i can get the CalendarId by connecting with the google calendar API so that i can store that in my database. I need to do this because i need to be able to Create events for every user in my database when they arn't logged in.

At this moment already have the refresh tokens. Now i can't us primar cause the User isn't been logged in so i can't use that one.

If its Possible i don't want to have that user need to fill in a inputfield to add there CalendarId. It needs to happen via api call if that can.

I hope there is a solution for this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

All users have a default calendar called "primary" this is also equivalent to the currently authenticated users email address as we.

You dont really need to store it in your database just use primary.

```
var result = service.Calendars.Get("primary").Execute();
```

Result

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"j3g2ipQvsbvz0_YlxYi3Ml2Fd7A\"",
 "id": "[REDACTED AS ITS MY EMAIL ADDRESS]",
 "summary": "Linda Lawton ",
 "description": "test",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen",
 "conferenceProperties": {
  "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
   "hangoutsMeet"
  ]
 }
}
```